# Why does command 'react-native run-ios' build fail after upgrade to 0.63.3?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-cli

I just updated to RN v0.63.3. I was having issues with `react-native run-ios` on previous react-native version after changing the name of the app, and the project/schemes had different names, never got that issue solved, everyone said to just upgrade.

now on v0.63.3 there is still an issue with failing build after `react-native run-ios`. this time the error is:

> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:
> CompileC /Users/vorousjames/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<OLD_NAME>-gdmnlxiprekjqhfiueouiidqhqnl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/<NEW_NAME>.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/<NEW_NAME>.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o
> /Users/Desktop/Development/App/iOS/<OLD_NAME>/AppDelegate.m
> normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
> (1 failure)

There is NO issue building/running from inside Xcode. ONLY with `react-native run-ios`

EDIT: I thought maybe there was an issue with the fact that I had the cli globally installed since I was just calling `react-native run-ios`. I believe that uses the global installation. so since its outdated, I uninstalled globally and tried to use the community package with `npx react-native run-ios`. now its giving another comileC error, but different.

> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:
> CompileC /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-gdmnlxiprekjqhfiueouiidqhqnl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNFirebase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNFirebaseMessaging.o
> /Users/Desktop/Development/App/node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/messaging/RNFirebaseMessaging.m
> normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
> CompileC /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-gdmnlxiprekjqhfiueouiidqhqnl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNFirebase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNFirebaseFirestore.o
> /Users/Desktop/Development/App/node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/firestore/RNFirebaseFirestore.m
> normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
> (2 failures)

This is completely killing my ability to iterate quickly, any advice is welcomed

react-native: 0.63.3
react-native-cli (global): 2.0.1
react-native-community/cli: ^4.8.0
Xcode: 12.0.1
iOS: 14.0.1

UPDDATE:

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "Aflare",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "android": "react-native run-android",
        "ios": "react-native run-ios",
        "start": "react-native start",
        "test": "jest",
        "lint": "eslint ."
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@react-native-community/cli": "^4.8.0",
        "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.2.2",
        "algoliasearch": "^3.16.0",
        "appcenter": "3.1.1",
        "appcenter-analytics": "3.1.1",
        "appcenter-crashes": "3.1.1",
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.27",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-native": "^0.63.3",
        "react-native-agora": "^3.1.3",
        "react-native-algolia-dropdown": "^1.6.0",
        "react-native-calendars": "^1.220.0",
        "react-native-chart-kit": "^4.3.0",
        "react-native-code-push": "^6.0.0",
        "react-native-extended-stylesheet": "^0.12.0",
        "react-native-firebase": "^5.6.0",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.2",
        "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.26.1",
        "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
        "react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
        "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.1",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.6.2",
        "react-native-screens": "^1.0.0-alpha.23",
        "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.4",
        "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
        "react-native-svg": "^9.13.6",
        "react-native-view-shot": "^3.1.2",
        "react-native-webview": "^9.4.0",
        "react-navigation": "^4.0.2",
        "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.3.3",
        "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
        "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
        "redux": "^4.0.4",
        "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.11.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "7.8.4",
        "@babel/runtime": "7.8.4",
        "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "1.1.0",
        "@types/react": "^16.9.46",
        "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
        "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
        "eslint": "6.7.2",
        "jest": "^25.1.0",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.59.0",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
    }
}
```

After @Florin's suggestion/process, there are now 14 build errors (from building with `npx react-native run-ios`):

> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:
> CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/Desktop/Development/App/node_modules/react-native-agora/ios/RCTAgora/Base/BeanCovertor.swift
> CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/Desktop/Development/App/node_modules/react-native-agora/ios/RCTAgora/Base/Callback.swift
> CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/Desktop/Development/App/node_modules/react-native-agora/ios/RCTAgora/Base/Extensions.swift
> CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/Desktop/Development/App/node_modules/react-native-agora/ios/RCTAgora/Base/MediaObserver.swift
> CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/Desktop/Development/App/node_modules/react-native-agora/ios/RCTAgora/React/PromiseCallback.swift
> CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/Desktop/Development/App/node_modules/react-native-agora/ios/RCTAgora/React/RCTAgoraRtcChannelModule.swift
> CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/Desktop/Development/App/node_modules/react-native-agora/ios/RCTAgora/React/RCTAgoraRtcEngineModule.swift
> CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/Desktop/Development/App/node_modules/react-native-agora/ios/RCTAgora/React/RCTAgoraRtcSurfaceViewManager.swift
> CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/Desktop/Development/App/node_modules/react-native-agora/ios/RCTAgora/Base/RtcChannel.swift
> CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/Desktop/Development/App/node_modules/react-native-agora/ios/RCTAgora/Base/RtcChannelEvent.swift
> CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/Desktop/Development/Slide/Slide/node_modules/react-native-agora/ios/RCTAgora/Base/RtcEngine.swift
> CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/Desktop/Development/App/node_modules/react-native-agora/ios/RCTAgora/Base/RtcEngineEvent.swift
> CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/Desktop/Development/App/node_modules/react-native-agora/ios/RCTAgora/Base/RtcSurfaceView.swift
> CompileC /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<Old_App_Name>-gdmnlxiprekjqhfiueouiidqhqnl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNFirebase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNFirebaseMessaging.o
> /Users/Desktop/Development/App/node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/messaging/RNFirebaseMessaging.m
> normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
> (14 failures)

the full build output, as far as it goes back in viscose's terminal is here: https://pastebin.com/XenEszNe

Xcode BuildPhases:
[image]

Comment: try to update react native cli , https://github.com/react-native-community/cli#updating-the-cli

Comment: im on 4.8.0, and GitHub states compatibility with RN v0.63 is  react-native-community/cli ^4.0.0, so why exactly are you advising to do this considering im already on a compatible version? @nazmul

Comment: actually though you have installed updated react native cli, sometime if you update any old project react native version, it still uses the cli version that it was created with. https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/1208 , maybe this link can give you some helpful info .

Comment: where do I find that version it was created with, the react-native dependencies in package-lock.json? I created the project with the legacy global `react-native-cli`

Comment: I would try creating a new project in 0.63.3, test it, then copy your app files to the new project.

Answer (score 5):

Most of the times when I get different outputs from console build and Xcode build I suspect a caching issue and I use next steps to fix the problem:

- **stop JS server**
- **remove derived data in Xcode**
- **run `pod install`**
- **re-install node_modules** (optional)
- **`npx watchman watch-del-all && yarn start --reset-cache`**
- **build using console and build using Xcode**

At this point you should have same output from both commands. If you get an error
read the entire error message carefully, there are plenty of chances to notice an issue with a module hidden deep in the error log.

Taking a close look at your error message it looks like something related to either derived data/cache or some pods that are not updated.

If you still encounter issue please attach to your question:

- `package.json` content,
- a full error message and
- content of Xcode->BuildPhases `bundle react-native code and images` script.

**UPDATE:**

If after upgrade to 0.63.3 you notice many issues related to React dependencies make sure the pod file is clean and contains only your special dependencies (the ones that do not support automatic linking or the ones for which their documentation specifies they need to be added to the Podfile) and not including the React ones. It should look like this:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'YourRnApp' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  target 'YourRnAppTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end

target 'YourRnApp-tvOS' do
  # Pods for RnDiffApp-tvOS

  target 'RnDiffApp-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

More info here:

https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.61.5&to=0.63.3

After a cleanup of the `Podfile`, clean cache, run a `pod install` and rebuild.

At this moment most of the errors should be gone.

Check in Xcode any remaining manual library link that is not needed and remove it (the ones that support auto-linking) and rebuild again.

If still not working check the `project.pbxproj` in the RN upgrade helper.

Take the errors one by one. Most of them should be fixable using the RN upgrade helper and other Stackoverflow answers.

Comment: thanks for responding, I tried your suggestion and updated question's details @FlorinDobre

Answer (score 0):

I think the Flipper library is having problems, so we need to manually use a version for now 'version 2.3.0'.

If you want to use flipper you can go with this solution at this moment:

- Go to  ios/Podfile in which you would see this:
- [enter to the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpnXf.png)

```
  require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
  require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

  platform :ios, '10.0'

  target 'pokeDex' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  target 'pokeDexTests' do
      inherit! :complete
      # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  # Important to use at this momemt version 2.30
  use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.3.0' })
  post_install do |installer|
      flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
  end

  target 'pokeDex-tvOS' do
  # Pods for pokeDex-tvOS

  target 'pokeDex-tvOSTests' do
      inherit! :search_paths
      # Pods for testing
  end
  end
```

If not you can comment the hole use_flipper install script like this:

```
  require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
  require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

  platform :ios, '10.0'

  target 'pokeDex' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  target 'pokeDexTests' do
      inherit! :complete
      # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  # lines commented
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  # use_flipper!
  # post_install do |installer|
  #   flipper_post_install(installer)
  # end
  end

  target 'pokeDex-tvOS' do
  # Pods for pokeDex-tvOS

  target 'pokeDex-tvOSTests' do
      inherit! :search_paths
      # Pods for testing
  end
  end
```